# How to check the source of sending message to IoT Hub in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have an environment setup with multiple devices able to send message to IoT Hub and goes to my other Function App at the moment. However I found out there are some devices is sending message through IoT Hub but it does not registered under the IoT Hub.

I felt strange as the device that do not registered in IoT Hub should not be sending message successfully through the IoT Hub. But the message is sent and reach to my next Function App after IoT Hub. So I would like to check the source of the message. Like in what method it used to send message, via API or some other method.

May I know where can I find any information regarding the source? I searched through Azure documents but points me to nowhere like this. I would like to find out how it sends message without registration in IoT Hub.

Sample Message that go through without registration in IoT Hub:

```
{
  "did": "TEST001",
  "msg": null,
  "pid": "0000-0001",
  "pld": {
     "data": "-0.015,41.895,7.199,23.49",
     "error": "00000000"
 },
 "dts": "2020-03-26T07:39:21.8969490Z"
}
```

What I am expecting is, since the device had no record in IoT Hub device list, is that this message will not go through IoT Hub, it will be dropped instead. However I saw this message goes through IoT Hub and reach my next Function App after IoT Hub. I wonder why is that.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include an example of the messages you were not expecting to see? That might help with the answers you can get from the community.

Comment: Have you tried routing? You can use IoThub routing and join with Device Twin property, If the device is not registered with IoThub won't forward your message.

Comment: Yes every message came to IoT Hub will route to the built-in event hub, then the event hub will trigger my Function App. And yes I was expecting that it will not forward however I can read the message from App Insight in my Function App.

Comment: Add one more route to the storage from the source = *Device Telemetry Messages*. The body of the blob file will have all details for each ingested telemetry data included the message system properties such as *connectionDeviceId, connectionAuthMethod, etc.*

Comment: @RomanKiss The thing is I am not the one who send that message... I was just providing the IoT Hub. But can I know under what circumstances will IoT Hub process the message even the device is not registered?

Comment: Have a look at this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry

Comment: you can Export all device identities in the IoT Hub identity registry to the blob storage, see the following REST POST https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/exportdevices Note, that only those devices can be connected to the iot hub.

Comment: Hey @Corene , I see that many suggestions were made to your question\issue. Can you post the answer so others can learn from it? Thanks!